# Reading xml data from file on desktop

Tags: c#, xml

Hello and today I want to find out how I can read an xml file in the following way, I have not been able to find ANYTHING like this or anythig simulaur to how I want to do this that works. I have an xml file with the following content format that has been disabled below this.

```
<smallusers>
<user id="1">
<name>John</name>
<motto>I am john, who are you?</motto>
</user>
<user id="2">
<name>Peter</name>
<motto>Hello everyone!</motto>
</user>
</smallusers>
<bigusers>
<user id="3">
<name>Barry</name>
<motto>Earth is awesome</motto>
</user>
</bigusers>
```

How can I put that into 2 string lists in csharp

Comment: What do you want to put in each list?

Answer (score 0):

1. Load it as a text file into a string or StringBuilder.
2. prefix it with <xml> and end it with </xml>
3. then use XmlDocument to load your xml

Comment: Why would you suggest XmlDocument rather than XDocument? LINQ to XML is a *much* friendlier API than XmlDocument, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

XML can have only one root tag.  You input has more than one root.  So you have to wrap your XML in a root like code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            input = string.Format("<Root>{0}</Root>", input);

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(input);

        }
    }
}
​
```